# Почему Boost требует файл "libboost_thread-vc143-mt-gd-x32-1_80.lib"

Tags: c++, boost, asio, boost.asio

Вроде бы Boost заявляется, как библиотека с одними заголовочными файлами.
Но почему компиляция простого примера из Boost Asio - требует какого то lib-файла - "libboost_thread-vc143-mt-gd-x32-1_80.lib" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604090/which-boost-libraries-are-header-only

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, благодарю. Теперь все понятно.